# Does XGetImage ever return a 32-bit depth XImage?

Tags: xlib

I am using XGetImage to read the pixels of an OpenGL window. The XImage that is returned shows a depth of 24-bits, but my OpenGL context has alpha values that I would like to be returned. Is there any way to get a 32-bit XImage from XGetImage, or does X already flatten the image to 24-bits?

Function call:

```
::XImage *winImage = XGetImage(dpy_i->dpy, wnd_i->wnd,
    x, y, width, height, 0xffffffff, ZPixmap);
```

GDB output:

```
(gdb) print *winImage
$2 = {width = 640, height = 512, xoffset = 0, format = 2, 
data = 0x7fffe72fd010 "\377\377\377", byte_order = 0, 
bitmap_unit = 32, bitmap_bit_order = 0, bitmap_pad = 32, 
depth = 24, bytes_per_line = 2560, bits_per_pixel = 32, 
red_mask = 16711680, green_mask = 65280, blue_mask = 255, 
obdata = 0x0, f = {create_image = 0x7ffff4b67810 <XCreateImage>, 
destroy_image = 0x7ffff4b665b0, get_pixel = 0x7ffff4b67520, 
put_pixel = 0x7ffff4b67450, sub_image = 0x7ffff4b67170, 
add_pixel = 0x7ffff4b66650}}
```

Comment: You probably need to create your window using 32 bit visual. I can successfully receive 32bit depth GetImage data from window I create here - https://github.com/sidorares/node-x11/blob/master/examples/smoketest/transpwindow.js

Comment: Hi @AndreySidorov I got 24bit but i get alpha in it, i gget BGRA, may you please see my solution below its very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to always get a 32bit image. This is my code, js-ctypes, i take a screenshot of all monitors.

https://github.com/Noitidart/_scratchpad/blob/c41012b16842f0769595033bd51a3801451319be/x11%20new%20way%20skel%20non%20jsm.js

This is my XImage struct after XGetImage:

```
"width:" "1280" "height:" "919" "xoffset:" "0" "format:" "2" "data:" "ctypes.char.ptr(ctypes.UInt64("0x7f850fe00000"))" "byte_order:" "0" "bitmap_unit:" "32" "bitmap_bit_order:" "0" "bitmap_pad:" "32" "depth:" "24" "bytes_per_line:" "5120" "bits_per_pixel:" "32" "red_mask:" "16711680" "green_mask:" "65280" "blue_mask:" "255" "_END_"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks like you also receive a 24-bit depth. Your bits_per_pixel is still 32, like mine. I was hoping to get a depth of 32 so that I could get alpha values in addition to the RGB.

Comment: Its quite intresting but I do get alpha, i get `BGRA`, notice how later in the code i swap it up.